# Create a left join with raw string data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a **list of e-mails** in a text file and a **Person** table with an email column.

**I need to know which of the emails are in the table, and which are not.**

So I was thinking in creating a query and do some kind of **left join** in my raw e-mail data with the Person table.

Now, I can do this:

```
select count(*) from PERSON p where p.EMAIL in ("email1@mail","XXXX@mail.com");
```

But, what I want is to return something like this:

```
Raw_Email         email

email1@mail.com   email1@mail.com
XXXX@mail.com     null
XXXXX             XXXXX
```

Comment: so you can do this: select Raw_Email from PERSON p where p.EMAIL in ("email1@mail","XXXX@mail.com")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the data from the text file into some table is the best option (the table may be temporary). Loaded data may then be used by the common way.

Another option is in using CSV Engine - but this engine must be available on your server instance (check `SHOW ENGINES` output). You must create table using this engine joined to your file then use this table by the common way.

Anycase you must have `CREATE TABLE` privilege.

The last option is in use `LOAD_FILE()` function. File content will be loaded as one string literal which may be parsed and splitted on separate values (this is easy enough on recent MySQL version). But you must to have `secure_file_privilege` option set, and if it is not empty then the file must be placed into specified folder. This option does not need in special additional privileges. Alternatively this function can be used in stored procedure where loaded data will be used in dynamic SQL.

Comment: HI @Akina, Do you know if there is a way to pass the array of e-mails in the query and the engine will understand it as a table? Like a UNION or something?

Comment: @edubriguenti JSON array, for example - if MySQL version is recent enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that MySQL supports direct access to text files -- at least without extensions.  So, you should import the data into the database.  The simplest method is [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Then you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to do what you want:

```
select e.raw_email, p.email
from staging_emails e left join
     persons p
     on p.email = e.raw_email;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Is there a way to pass the array of e-mails in the query and the engine will understand it as a table? Like a UNION or something?

Comment: @edubriguenti . . . That would be a different question, where you describe loading a CSV file into your application.

Comment: I meant create a query in the mysql workbench. I have thousands of e-mail and I want to know which of them are inside the table and which aren't.

Comment: @edubriguenti . . . You should start by loading the emails into the database.

Comment: Yeah...I thought that might had a trick to do it without loading the data. Thanks you.